# Convert list of dictionaries to pandas DF without using too much memory

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, memory

I am trying to make a pandas array of over 500,000 rows and 20 columns in a loop where a new row is added on every new pass of the for loop. I tried doing that by using the `pd.DataFrame.append()` method but it seems to be very with this many loops:

```
df_results = pd.DataFrame(columns = fldIds)

for i in range(0, 500000):
    msg = parseMsg(rawMsg)
    dfDict = {}

    for keys in fldIds:
        tempVal = getattr(msg, keys)
        if tempVal != 0:
            dfDict[keys] = tempVal

    df_results = df_results.append(dfDict)
```

As an alternative I've tried following some previous suggestions on the topic and making a list of dictionaries of data and then converting it into the pandas dataframe when the loop is finished:

```
list_results = []

for i in range(0, 500000):
    msg = parseMsg(rawMsg)
    dfDict = {}

    for keys in fldIds:
        tempVal = getattr(msg, keys)
        if tempVal != 0:
            dfDict[keys] = tempVal

    list_results.append(dfDict)

df_results = pd.DataFrame(list_results)
```

This has made the whole process much faster. The problem with this method is that a list of dictionaries uses a lot of memory and it just so happens that I am quite memory limited. The memory used by df_results itself is much less than that of the list_results.

Is there maybe an alternative way to group the results before passing them to a dataframe that could save me some memory usage?

Comment: What does `parseMsg` returns?

Comment: It's a google protobuf message parser. Basically, it's an object where I have some fields that I'm interested in in. So in the nested loop I extract those fields with a for loop into a dictionary and then append that dictionary to a list

Comment: Whats the average time your script is taking for adding 500000 records?

Comment: If converting a list to dataframe it takes around 2 minutes, but with pandas append method I've always stopped it after 8 minutes or so.